# Preferences not showing summary in PreferencesFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I have a preferences screen (`Fragment`) that has some preferences set from an xml file. The only thing i call in the `Fragment` is `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_main);` in the onCreate method.

Now, everything works well except for the "summary" section in my preferences, for instance if you have an EditTextPreference and you enter some text, that text should be visible under the preference in smaller letters.

I'm using a custom controll for a preference (but it also doesn't work for any of the official Preferences), that extends `DialogPreference`. If i set the summary like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    if (positiveResult) {
        setSummary("Some summary");
    }
}
```

It works but only as long as i dont leave the screen, when i return it's not there anymore.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preference screen does not automatically display the summary data. You need to do it in code. Here is a code fragment you could use in your onCreate() method. Add it after the call to `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_main);`

```
for(int i = 0; i < getPreferenceScreen().getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
    initializeSummary(getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(i));
}
```

The initializeSummary() method is like this:

```
private void initializeSummary(Preference p)
{
    if(p instanceof ListPreference) {
        ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference)p;
        p.setSummary(listPref.getEntry());
    }
    if(p instanceof EditTextPreference) {
        EditTextPreference editTextPref = (EditTextPreference)p;
        p.setSummary(editTextPref.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! Is there any particular reason why it doens't display it automatically? Also, another quick question, how do i read a preference from sharedpreferences in my custom preferences class?

Comment: I think Android OS doesn't do that automatically. To read the shared preference, use `SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);`. Then, you can read the value using the key.

Comment: Thanks! Just a note for future readers, you have to rerun the updatePrefSummary on every preference that is a PreferenceCategory. Also, now the summary isnt set when i return from a default EditTextPreference. Any way around this, other than extending the class?

Comment: To update the summary on every change, override this in the fragment: `@Override
 public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key)
 {
  updatePrefSummary(findPreference(key));
 }`

Comment: If the `ListPreference` is wrapped under `PreferenceCategory`, it will not reach `ListPreference`. You will need another `if` to handle `instance of PreferenceCategory`, which is not difficult with recursion. However, this does not seem to work.. I wonder if this is because the selected value takes the place of the summary.

Comment: I found where my problem is. I overwrite the summary `onPreferenceChange`... so yes, this method works with another `if` to handle `PreferenceCategory` like I mentioned previously.

Answer (score 1):

As @Anthony had mentioned in the comments there might be `PreferenceCategory` instances in your preferences XML. We can handle them recursively as follows.

```kotlin
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

     /**
     * Initialises the summary of EdittextPreference's and ListPreference's 
     * that might be nested in PreferenceCategories. 
     */
    private fun summarize(pref: Preference) {
        when (pref) {
            is PreferenceCategory -> {
                for (i in 0 until pref.preferenceCount) {
                    summarize(pref.getPreference(i))
                }
            }
            is EditTextPreference -> pref.summary = pref.text
            is ListPreference -> pref.summary = pref.entry
            else -> {
                Log.w("Summarize", "Ignoring preference of type ${pref::class.java}")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
        for (i in 0 until preferenceScreen.preferenceCount) {
            summarize(preferenceScreen.getPreference(i))
        }
}
```